# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a admin portal where all the documents from database are configured and manipulated.

We have a collection for language translation which contains a lot of document.

And admin can modify all this document.

If admin opens any other collection it works fine. But when he opens this language translation collection the systems gets slower and after few mins I found this error.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

513530251 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.7 (1458.0) -> 1397.7 (1458.0) MB, 2719.4 / 2 ms [allocation failure] [
GC in old space requested].
513533054 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.7 (1458.0) -> 1397.7 (1458.0) MB, 2802.9 / 2 ms [last resort gc].
513535773 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.7 (1458.0) -> 1397.6 (1458.0) MB, 2718.9 / 2 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000002D0BF1B4639 <JS Object>
    1: new constructor(aka WritableState) [_stream_writable.js:88] [pc=0000036F0D0CA7F9] (this=00000
153740AD191 <a WritableState with map 0000017D64825C01>,options=00000065E299D0F1 ,stream=00000153740ACFA1 )
    3: Writable [_stream_writable.js:143] [pc=0000036F0D0CA0C2] (this=00000153740ACFA1 <a Socket with map 0000017D...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Can anyone help me what can solve this issue???

I start my node with the following syntax.

`set node_debug=foo&& node --max-old-space-size=8192 server.js`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Node installed through Homebrew.
Try to run `` vim `which npm` ``

and change:
`#!/usr/bin/env node`
to:
`#!/usr/bin/env node --max-old-space-size=2048`

Update: By the way, I have fixed this error by following these [simple steps](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689)

Answer (score 0):

Add an environment variable:

```
TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
```